# Nullable property is making model invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can someone explain why the below model becomes invalid in the LogIn action method? And what I should do to resolve it?

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeEmailId { get; set; }
}
```

### HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmployeeViewModel evm = new EmployeeViewModel();
    evm.EmployeeEmailId = "sdf@gmail.com";

    return LogIn(evm);
}

public ActionResult LogIn(EmployeeViewModel modelEnt)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)     //Invalid Employee Id
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be marked invalid as there's no `Required` attribute that you are showing on `EmployeeId`

Comment: There's no `EmployeeName` on `evm` either it appears?

Comment: If you examine the `ModelState` does it give you anything in the errors for that field? I'd expect it to be telling you why it considered it not valid...

Comment: It could only be invalid if your submitting a value for `EmployeeId` and that value is not a valid `int`

Comment: You're just calling one method from another with an object, there's none of the pipelining happening that will affect the underlying `ModelState` at all.

Comment: Consider using a `LoginViewModel` class instead, this way you don't need to have any fields you won't be using.

Comment: @MarkC. The employeeId and name will be identified by the DB after the above code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not presently passing any values to either ID or name. Only Email is being populated